# Create a Patern Rank, Based on THE VALUE(s) IN A COLUMN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have data like this -

[image]

I want to create one more column name Pattern and it looks like this -

[image]

How to create this column -

It is based on the column '**NAME**'. It should Rank Starting from the Row having Parent_ID=(ContentID of the row having Parent ID 1)
It should increase by one and should make the same Group if it get's **'Only For'/'Not For'** in the column **NAME**.

It will work on the group of **Jill_Equipment_ID,Req_Group,Operand.**.
As my complete data in broken into these groups and it will have multiple Jill_Equipment_ID and for each ID multiple Req_Group and for each group multiple Operands.

Please help me in getting it solved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not paste data as a picture... Try to set up a small and reduced example and you might read this:http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Which SqlServer versionare you running ?  Have you tried "window functions" ?

Comment: using 2014 version. Is it possible to achieve the objective with the same ?

Comment: I have tried rank, row_number , dense_rank. Nothing works as my ranking should change only when there is Only For/Not For found in the column "NAME". I am thinking it can be done by creating temp table and then joining. Still not sure about the correct approach :(